# C++ What is this usage of the + operator called? and what is the purpose?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

I recently saw an example in an operator overloading review where they talked about how the + operator was essentially a function with 2 parameters.

With a bit of poking I decided to look at this a bit deeper and found that calling + like a function does indeed work, just not how you would expect... eg:

```
int first = 6;
int second = 9;
int result = +(second,first);//result=6
```

The assembly for this is

```
int result = +(second,first);
mov         eax,dword ptr [first]  
mov         dword ptr [result],eax
```

The call to + is simply moving the last parameter into eax.

Can anyone tell me the purpose of this and/or what it is called?

Comment: nice question, I'll put it in the same category with [What is the name of the “-->” operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator)

Comment: Having seen the answer, I think that is super fair. I feel like a complete idiot.

Comment: I was actually not ironic :) It is a fair question and I bet many people are first mislead by this funny form, especially if having some functional programming background.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two parts to the expression `+(second,first)` - and neither of them is a function call.

The expression `(second, first)` uses the rare *comma operator*, which evaluates each expression in turn and the result of the expression is the *last* expression evaluated.

The `+` in this case is just a unary `+` operator, like saying `+5` or `-8`. So the result of your expression is `6`, the value of `first`.

You can, however, call the `operator +` like this:

```
int result = operator +(second, first);
```

Comment: Rare? for (p = root, last = NULL; p != NULL; last = p, p = p->next) ;-)

Comment: @RichardPennington: It's a lot more rare than the usual use of comma, which is separating function arguments in a function call.

Comment: There's no `operator+` for `int`s. (Well, there is such a signature but only for overload resolution purposes; it can't be called.)

Comment: @T.C. for all fundamental types

Comment: @T.C.: There is, but only for the purpose of operator overload resolution.  You'll find it in 13.6